# How to access multiple object in request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm passing two object in a POST request with axios from client (js) to server (php with laravel)

orderData and userData contain mutliple value, nested array...

```
  export const sendMail = (orderData, userData) => async () => {
  await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL2}mail`,
    data: { orderData: orderData, userData: userData },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log('update mail send with success');
  });
};
```

Then, in laravel, i would like to access data.

i need to access name/email in userData, and title in orderData

What i have tried :

```
 $data = $request->all();
        $orderDatas = $data['orderData'];
        $UserDatas = $data['userData'];

        $userName = $UserDatas->get('name');
        $userEmail = $UserDatas->get('email');
        $title = $orderDatas->get('title');
```

I also know how to access data if i only pass one object in my request (for exemple, if I only pass "userData", i know " `$userName = $request->get('name');`" will get me the user name.

my error : `"Call to a member function get() on array"`.

Comment: what u get if u do `dd($request->all())`?

Comment: `$UserDatas` is an array, not a collection. So try something like `$userName = $UserDatas[0]['name'];` Same for email and title.

Comment: Thanks Can Vural, i will try but i things it will work.
I was thinking that UserDatas was still an object because when i console.log type of in client side, it's tell me that he is an object. Does it change when i'm passing from client to server ?

Comment: `$request->all()` returns an array. As simple as that. [Docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.html#method_all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not call get() on array as error describes this. Instead you should try this while using array.

```
 $data = $request->all();
 $orderDatas = $data['orderData'];
 $UserDatas = $data['userData'];

 $userName = $UserDatas['name'];
 $userEmail = $UserDatas['email'];
 $title = $orderDatas['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `$request->all()`, as I assume the method has `Request $request` as part of the parameters.

`orderData` will be inside `$request->orderData`

`userData` will be inside `$request->userData`

`print_r`, `var_dump` or `dd` will show you the structure of `$request->userData` and `$request->orderData` so you can further use this data. I don't know the structure of those, but we can pretend the `name` key exists with `$request->userData['name']` for example key access.

ie: `var_dump($request->orderData);`

A side note that the axios could be shortened to

```
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL2}mail`, {orderData, userData}).then...
```